# Android OpenGL ES: Resuming/pausing an Activity

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-activity, lifecycle

I am having difficulties understanding the right way to split initialization and maintenance of application state between Activity, GLSurfaceView and Renderer.
Let's say I have a game with complex objects, complex state and want to preserve the state and load it on each onResume.
My initialization goes like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gamescreenView = (GLGameScreenSurface) findViewById(R.id.GLGamescreenView);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) { 
        Game.init();
        resuming = false;
    } else {
        gamedata = (GameData) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("gamedata");
        resuming = true;
    }
    renderer = new MyRenderer(this, gamedata, gamescreenView,
            handle, resuming);
    gamescreenView.setRenderer(renderer);
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    gamescreenView.onPause();
    gamedata = renderer.gamedata;
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    gamescreenView.onResume();
    renderer.gamedata= gamedata;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putSerializable("gamedata", renderer.gamedata);
}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  gamedata = (UniverseHolder) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("gamedata");
}
```

here is my Renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
public WideOpenRenderer(Context context, UniverseHolder universe, GLGameScreenSurface gamescreenView, Handler handler, boolean resuming) {
    this.context = context;
    this.handler = handler;
    parent = gamescreenView;
    this.gamedata = gamedata;
    this.resuming = resuming;
}
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            Log.d("mydebug", "" + resuming);
            gamedata.init();
}
...
```

But it does not work this way and resuming is always false according to the log.